# Get form from the associated input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Saying that I have this HTML form:

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="input_el" type="text">
  <input id="submit_el" type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to get the form element starting from one of its input elements, so I could write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input_el').form().validate();
$('#submit_el').form().submit();
</script>
```

That is, `$('#input_el').form()` should return `$('#form')` . Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do

```
$('#input_el').closest('form')
```

Comment: +1 This is the solution you'd want to choose in the event that you refactor your markup and your inputs become nested inside a container of any sort.

Comment: I would like that jQuery implement a method that retrieves the related form from a form element... I find it very useful. A very primitive implementation could be: `jQuery.fn.form = function() {
    return this.closest('form');
};` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("input").closest("form").validate().submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input_el').parent('form')
```

or

```
$('#input_el').parent()
```